# Adding JSON data to Chart.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, chart.js

I've been trying to populate my chart with data I get from an ajax request but I can not seem to figure it out. Could anyone help?

```
var simple_forms;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: "user_id="+user_id,
    success: function(data){ simple_forms = data; },
    error: function(data) {  }
});
```

This is the output from the `data` = `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

```
var weekly_line_data = {
    labels : ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    datasets : [
    {
        label: "Simple Forms",fillColor : "transparent",strokeColor : "#53A3EB",pointColor : "#53A3EB",pointStrokeColor : "#fff",pointHighlightFill : "#2980b9",pointHighlightStroke : "#2980b9",
        data : simple_forms
    }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("weekly_line_data").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(weekly_line_data, {responsive: true,scaleShowGridLines : true,scaleGridLineWidth : 1,datasetStrokeWidth : 1,pointDotRadius : 5});
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the AJAX call to finish before your are trying to draw your chart?

Comment: It appears I was not. Thank you @m90

Comment: @m90 if I have something like `[["1","0","0","0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]]`, how would I get the first section of this in js? I'd appreciate it

Comment: Use `data[0]`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Had to make sure to have `dataType: 'json'`